# Таблица в приложении Windows 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Как в Visual Studio 2013 создать таблицу с колонками и рядами для приложения на Windows 8?

Comment: @Кирюха, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: GridView  если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: В конструкторе разве нет таблиц?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нужно понимать, что бесплатный сыр только в мышеловке. Есть стандартный гид,  но вам он сможет помочь только при простых требованиях к возможностям. Имеется целый ряд фирм, выпускающих комерческие гриды, но такие компоненты стоят приличных денег. Лично мне из коммерческих больше нравится telerik.com. Можете себя утешить, что в других технологиях еще хуже.

Если же вы будете создавать приложение на бесплатных компоненты,  рекомендую xceed wpf toolkit community edition.